# PHP parsing empty nodes from XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

PHP newbie here. I've written a script that parses XML reports fetched from an API. In some of the reports certain nodes don't exist so when I try to get the value from the node, I get the error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object." I'm not sure how to handle this issue since I have hundreds of lines like the following which assign node values to an associative array.

```
$reportItems['propertyBaths'] = $report187->PropertyProfile->PropertyCharacteristics->Baths[0];
$reportItems['propertyRooms'] = $report187->PropertyProfile->PropertyCharacteristics->TotalRooms[0];
$reportItems['propertyYear'] = $report187->PropertyProfile->PropertyCharacteristics->YearBuilt[0];
```

In cases where nodes doesn't exist, I want to assign an empty string instead. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this that wouldn't entail drastically changing what I've already written, something like:

```
$reportItems['propertyBaths'] = $report187->PropertyProfile->PropertyCharacteristics->Baths[0] || ""
```

If I had anticipated this issue, I would have wrapped each assignment in a function with error handling, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler approach given what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to make sure the node exists:

```
if(isset($node->SomeValue)) {
    $arr['item'] = $node->SomeValue;
} else {
    $arr['item'] = ''
}
```

Also, as Dave notes in the comments below, you can also use [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/property_exists):

```
if (property_exists($node, 'someValue')) {
    $arr['item'] = $node->SomeValue;
} else {
    $arr['item'] = '';
}
```

Comment: That's nodes in XML document, not in PHP. In PHP they are class properties, therefore `property_exists()` would make more sense, like `if (property_exists($node, 'someValue'))`

Answer (score 0):

you can just do something like

```
$reportItems['propertyBaths'] = ''.$report187->PropertyProfile->PropertyCharacteristics->Baths[0];
```

which will automatically convert the result of the xml child to string and return emptystring if it doesnt exist. exactly what you want without testing